# Elementary question in Group Theory with less prerequisite

Tags: group-theory

Here I am posing a problem, which my beginning students of algebra were discussing for long time.

**Question:** Without using theorem of Cauchy or Sylow, can we show that a group of order $15$ contains elements of order $3$ and $5$?

One can use Lagrange's theorem here.

---

I know the solution using Cauchy theorem. But these things I have not yet taught in the class.

Comment: order of element divides order of group

Comment: Pick an element in your group. Show that the set generated by this element is a subgroup of the group and apply Lagrange.

Comment: this will show that the elements will have order 3,5,or 15. Suppose I assume that all the elements (except 1) have order 3. I should arrive at a contradiction. But I couldn't proceed further.

Comment: The action of $G$ on its order-3 subgroups gives us a subgroup of $S_7$ where all nontrivilal elements look like $(1\,2\,3)(4\,5\,6)$ (two fixpoints would mean that $G$ has a subgroup of order $9\nmid 15$). "Of course" the product of permutations of this cycle type is not again of this type, but I don't see how to show that without gazillins of case distinctoins.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It may be easier to use the action by multiplication on the left cosets of a subgroup of order $3$. Then nontrivial images must be single $3$-cycles, and you quickly find that you either have two permutations like $(1,2,3),(1,2,4)$  or $(1,2,3),(1,4,5)$, which you can mutliply together to get permutations that do not have order $3$. I am not sure how worthwhile this exercise it - it might be easier to learn Cauchy's theorem!

Answer (score 2):

We assume the group is not cyclic. If it generates $G$ we are done. Otherwise by Lagrange it has order $3$ or $5$. If the order is $5$ then then let $C$ be the group generated by $g$. Since the index of $C$ is $3$ and $3$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ we conclude that $C$ is normal and so we take $G\rightarrow \frac{G}{C}$ the natural isomorphism $\varphi$. We take a generator of $\frac{G}{C}$ and consider its preimage. call this preimage $h$ and the subgroup generated by it $H$. Since $H$ maps to all of $\frac{G}{C}$ we apply the first isomorphism theorem to the restriction of the natural isomorphism to $H$ and so $\frac{H}{ker(\varphi|_H)}\cong\frac{G}{C}$. This tells us the order of $H$ is a multiple of $3$ and since $H$ is not cyclic this means the order of $H$ is $3$.

So if there is an element of order $5$ there is an element of order $3$.

I'm not sure how to prove it the other way around.

Comment: If all elements $g\ne e$ have order $5$, then the size of the group must be of the form $4n +1$, of which $15$ is not. No need to invoke normality.

Comment: Yes! But if all the elements have order 3 (except identity), then ...?

Comment: @Groups I don't see a quick and super elementary way out of that situation.

Comment: @IttayWeiss thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Given two distinct subgroups of order $5$ $H$ and $K$, $H \cap K = \{e\}$ (because otherwise the element in common would generate them both).

So if all elements except $1$ have order $5$, the number of elements in the group must be $4n + 1$, which $15$ isn't.

So that means that there must be an element of order $3$.

Now assume that all elements have order 3. Again, by the same reasoning the number of elements in the group must be in the form $2n + 1$. So there are $n = 7$ subgroups of order $3$. I can't get further than that.

Comment: To finish your answer, use the class equation to show that $G$ has nontrivial center, so $G/Z(G)$ has order $5$ or $1$. But then the image of any element in $G/Z(G)$ is trivial (because the image has order $3$ or $1$), so $G/Z(G)$ is trivial and $G$ is abelian. When $G$ is abelian the claim is easy. Of course, with the same amount of work we could just prove Cauchy's theorem..